# Domain and range of $g(x) = 3 /(x-4)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $$g(x) = \frac{3}{x-4}$$

for the domain, I find, $\{x|x\ne 4\}$'

and for the range

$$\{y|- \infty < y < 0 < y < \infty \}$$

$$\{y| 0 < |y| < \infty \}$$

Firstly, have I got that Range right? Secondly, if it is correct, which is the more preferred way to write it? Or is there a more appropriate way than these two attempts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This all looks right to me. For the range, you can certainly notice that the fraction can never be zero (since the denominator can't be zero), but you can just test values of $y$ to see if the fraction can ever be equal to $y$ as follows.

Given a value $y$, you want to see if there is an $x$ such that $g(x)=y$. Then
$$\frac{3}{x-4}=y$$
$$\iff (x-4)y=3\tag{provided $x\neq 4$}$$
$$\iff x-4 = \frac 3y\tag{provided $y\neq 0$}$$
$$\iff x = 4 + \frac 3y$$

Note that there is no value of $y$ for which you obtain $x=4$, since it would then imply $3/y=0$ (never true for any $y$), so we don't need to worry about the first proviso.

The second proviso says that this solution is valid for all values of $y$ except for $0$. It doesn't say there isn't a solution for $y=0$, it says that this method of obtaining a solution isn't value for $y=0$. But it's easy to see that there isn't a solution for the case $y=0$ since you would have

$$\frac{3}{x-4}=0$$
$$\iff 3 = 0(x-4)\tag{provided $x\neq 4$}$$
$$\iff 3 = 0\tag{never true}$$

Comment: Thanks @MPW that was well explained.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, domain is $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{4\} = \{x \in \mathbb{R} | x \ne 4\}$, and the range is $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\} = \{x \in \mathbb{R} | x \ne 0\}$.

Note that

- your function in the title disagrees with the one in the body (but answers stay the same)
- first notation of the range is wrong

Comment: Thanks for that @gt6989b . so $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{4\}$ is, in words, all real numbers except for 4?

Comment: @Bucephalus correct

Comment: Thanks to you too @gt6989b

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the range is correct.

The range can be written as $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0\}$.

To prove that it is indeed the range, suppose $y \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0\}$, we let $x = \frac3y +4$, then $$\frac{3}{\frac{3}{y}+4-4}=y$$

Suppose $y=0$, then there can't be a preimage or we might lead to $3=0$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks to you too @SiongThyeGoh

Answer (score 1):

You are correct:

Suppose $\;a\in\;$Range$(g)\;$, then there exists $\;x\neq4\;$ s.t.:

$$\frac3{x-4}=a\implies ax=4a+3\implies x=\frac{4a+3}a$$

From the above it should be clear that it must be $\;a\neq0\;$, and also:

$$x=\frac{4a+3}a=4\implies 3=0\,,\,\,\text{which is clearly absurd, thus}\;\;x\neq4$$

Both ways you choose to write your function's range look weird, to say the least...but the second one is slightly less odd. In fact, it is enough to write

$$\text{Range}\,(g)=\Bbb R\setminus\{0\} = (-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)\;,\;\;\text{or simply to remark}\;\;y\neq0$$

Comment: Thanks again @DonAntonio I would have picked yours but you probably needed one more step in your absurdity to not lose me.I could not understand what you were talking about until I read MPW's